# Force inheriting class to implement methods as protected

Tags: scala

I've a got a trait:

```
trait A {
  def some: Int
}
```

and an object mixing it in:

```
object B extends A {
  def some = 1
}
```

The question is, is there a way to declare `some` in `A` in a way that all inheriting objects have to declare the `some` method as protected for example? Something that would make the compiler yell at the above implementation of `some` in `B`?

**UPDATE:**
Just a clarification on the purpose of my question: Within an organization, there are some software development standards that are agreed upon. These standards, for example 'The `some` method is to always be declared as `private` when inheriting from `trait A`', are in general communicated via specs or documents listing all the standards or via tools such as Jenkins, etc... I am wondering if we could go even further and have these standards right in the code, which would save a lot of time correcting issues raised by Jenkins for example.

**UPDATE 2:**
A solution I could think of is as follows:

```
abstract class A(
   protected val some: Int   
){
  protected def none: String
}
```

Use an `abstract class` instead of a `trait` and have the functions or values that I need to be `protected` by default passed in the constructor:

```
object B extends A(some = 1) {
  def none: String = "none"
}
```

Note that in this case, `some` is by default `protected` unless the developer decides to expose it through another method. However, there will be no guarantee that, by default, `none` will be `protected` as well.

This works for the use case I described above. The problem with this implementation is that if we have a hierarchy of `abstract class`es, we would have to add the all the constructor parameters of the parent to every inheriting child in the hierarchy. For example:

```
abstract class A(
   protected val some: Int   
)

abstract class B(
    someImp: Int,
    protected val none: String    
) extends A(some = someImp)

object C extends B(
  someImp = 1, 
  none = "none"    
)
```

In contrast, using `trait`s, we could have been able to simply write:

```
trait A{
  protected val some: Int   
}

trait B extends A{
  protected val none: String    
} 

object C extends B{
  val some = 1
  val none = "none"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any straight way to restrict subclasses from choosing a wider visibility for inherited members.

It depends on why you want to hide the field some, but if the purpose is just to forbid end-users from accessing the field, you can use a slightly modified form of the cake pattern:

```
trait A {
  trait A0 {
      protected def some: Int
  }
  def instance: A0
}

object B extends A {
  def instance = new A0 {
    def some = 5
  }
}
```

Yeah, it looks nasty but the compiler will yell when someone tries to do:

```
B.instance.some
```

Another version of this solution is just to do things like in your example (adding protected to the member "some" in A), but to never expose directly a reference of type B (always return references of type A instead)

Comment: This would solve part of the issue, the end user would not be able to use the some method. But what I really want is that the developer inheriting from my trait would be forced to declare it as private or protected. Because this would not prevent future developers from declaring the `some` method in a way that would expose it.